# Linking to 32bit shared object file in 32 bit enviornment generates ELFCLASS64 error

Tags: c++, linux, qt, linker, intel

**System** :  I'm running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 on a i32 chipset.

**Build Info** : I'm using C++ 11 with Qt 4.8.1 and GCC.

**Problem** :  I am developing a project that depends on in-house developed libraries hereafter mentioned to as **slug**. These libraries are built into .so files via the traditional "cmake ." then "make all" process. After the .so files are generated from cmake, I copy the .so files into a sub-directory of my project so that I can test that they are working before I install them into /usr/lib. Then I provide Qt (in my .pro file) with a absolute path to each library and build my application. My application finds these local libraries and compiles without errors or warnings. However, when I run my application (via command line) I receive the following error:

```
    error while loading shared libraries: libslugSpec.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

However, when I build the slug libraries on a 64 bit environment and link to them in a 64 bit environment my application runs perfectly. So, I figured I built the .so files for a 64 bit environment,and proceeded to edit the CMakeLists.txt file used to build the libraries. I add numerous 32 bit compilation and linking flags, shared object module flags, in addition to cuda (which slug relies on) bitness flags . No matter what combination of flags I tried, the libraries generated kept causing the error when running my application executable. So I decided to run the **readelf -h** command on each shared object file and check to see if they were really 64 bit. I found out that none of them are in fact, all producing logs similar to the following: (output for one of 3 .so files)

```
readelf -h libslugSpec.so 
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF32
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
Machine:                           Intel 80386
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x10150
Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          511960 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x0
Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         7
Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         38
Section header string table index: 35
```

So now I am completely at a loss and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Any illumination into how this could be happening would be a huge help.

For reference, here are the flags I am providing in the qt .pro file that builds my application:

```
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += "-std=gnu++0x"

    QT  += core gui opengl
    TARGET = source
    TEMPLATE = app
    CONFIG+= wwwidgets


    #linux specific settings
    unix:!macx{
        LIBS +=  -lGLEW -lGLU  /home/alex/Dropbox/brain-viz/source/lib/libslugUtil.so /home/alex/Dropbox/brain-viz/source/lib/libslugSpec.so /home/alex/Dropbox/brain-viz/source/lib/libslugSim.so
    }

    #windows specific settings
    win32{
       LIBS += -lglew32 -lwwwidgets4d
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message:

> error while loading shared libraries: libslugSpec.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Is *not* consistent with this output:

> ```
> readelf -h libslugSpec.so 
> ELF Header:
> Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
> Class:                             ELF32
> ```

Conclusion: you load a *different* version of `libslugSpec.so` from the one you ran `readelf -h` on.

Find out *which* `libslugSpec.so` is loaded at runtime by doing this:

```
LD_DEBUG=files,libs /path/to/your/executable
```

Then run `readelf -h` on *that* library, and confirm that it is in fact `ELF64`.

Finally replace it with the version you've built (or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to pick up your version before "system" one), and the problem will be solved.

Comment: You were exactly right! I must have installed a copy of libSlugSpec from a previous build into /usr/lib. Thank you so much!